# Counting vowels code breakdown for python

Tags: python

I'm new to python. I've recently begun playing around with the concepts to try and expand my understanding and application. I tried a simple problem being "count the vowels in a string". I was able to solve it however, i was looking at other people's code and found this:

```
def vowel_count (string):
    find_vowel = 0

    for letter in string.lower():
        if letter in "aeiou":
            find_vowel += 1

    return find_vowel
```

Can anyone break down this code line by line for me please.
I'm especially a bit disoriented with understanding the concept of starting off with `find_vowel = 0` and the part where is has `find_vowel +=1`. I interpreted this as `find_vowel` being assigned a new value of 1 as it was added to the previous value of zero, but i'm not sure exactly how it is connected or counts the vowels exactly. I ran the code though and it works so I'd just like to know the finer details behind it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you asking what `+=` means?

Comment: well `x += 1` is just a shortcut (syntactic sugar) for writing `x = x + 1`. So when you see the construct of `x = 0; .... ; x += 1` that's usually an implementation of a counter. In that case - counter of vowels in a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're asking what `+=` means, then I can tell you that.

`+=` is an operator that adds to a variable. It increments a variable by any amount, and it is a very helpful shortcut.

Say you have a variable called `money`.

To add to money, you could do this:

```py
money = money + 1
```

A shorcut to that would be:

```py
money += 1
```

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Very helpful. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: @GianlucRobinson Can you upvote this question and accept it? Thanks, I would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

An implementation with better variable naming would be this:

```
def count_vowels(string):
    count = 0

    for letter in string.lower():
        if letter in "aeiou":
            count += 1

    return count
```

The `+=` operator *increments*, or adds 1 to, the `count` value. Every time a vowel is found, the value of `count` increases by 1, representing the presence of that vowel in the string.

Comment: Oh! I understand. Thanks for the feedback, this was extremely helpful!